# flexible css button no images

Tags: image, css, button, resizable

need your brains!!

i am hoping to make a button with no images, as with CSS3, that will scale based on the verbiage in the button. I have tried a few things but I am unable to get anything to work.

For Example:
the button has a minimum width of say 95px

and that's great for HOME or ABOUT US
but if i have copy that is like
Dallas City Council Team

It would be great if the button would get wider.

Can anyone help me with this? pretty please? I've driven myself insane!!!

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: Hey, can you post your code and give an indication of the things you have already tried.

Comment: @MichaelEvans well, i'm trying to figure it out by reviewing a variety of code online. I found this code, and have it working - although - the button is really large! but it doesn't increase in size when additional text is added. 
(the code is too long - it won't let me drop it in here)

and here's the code for the button. 
<div id="shiny-blue" class="css3-button">No Images but no scaling!!</div>

and here's a page to view what's currently 'being tested'. 
http://orders.modassystems.com/sample-form/

Comment: okay - so i added the code on the face of the example link i sent  you. the forum wouldn't take it bc of the way some of the long lines format. i kept getting an error trying to paste it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i wound up resolving my issue. it's not as pretty as i'd like but it's going to work. i was having trouble setting the minimum width, so i just changed it all to have a fixed width of 200 because that's all the space i have available. that being said, if you remove the DISPLAY: INLINE-BLOCK; it will go back to scaling based on the menu button copy (even if you leave the width:200px; in there)

i also had to create 'left menu anchor' classes because all of our links were blue and didn't show up very well but that was just a quick copy, rename and color change.

thank you guys for all of your help! i truly appreciate it. hope this helps some peeps in the future.

```css
.left_menu_btn_css {
  background: #39a7f0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #39a7f0, #2979ab);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #39a7f0, #2979ab);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #39a7f0, #2979ab);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #39a7f0, #2979ab);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #39a7f0, #2979ab);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
  -moz-border-radius: 5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left_menu_btn_css:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question, but if you want to make a button class scale depending on the text in the button, you shouldn't give it any width and just style it with padding

Comment: well, i was hoping to have a minimum width of the button at least - so i can try to fit it in a given area. I'll add the code i have to the original post.